# HTTP request being sent correctly but returns incorrect value/result

Tags: java, apache, http, bing, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to send an http request to bing's spell checking api using a GET request. I checked my parameters and headers on https://www.hurl.it/ and it returned a proper json with the spelling errors properly, however when I send the request from my java app it returns this json with NO spelling errors detected (therefore, text parameter HAS to be empty somehow). I'm definitely passing the correct key in the header because that part isn't sending an error and the code is 200 (success).

My string: "my funger is harting me"

My code returned:

```
{"_type":"SpellCheck","flaggedTokens":[]}
```

Hurl.it returned:

```
{  
   "_type":"SpellCheck",
   "flaggedTokens":[  
      {  
         "offset":3,
         "token":"funger",
         "type":"UnknownToken",
         "suggestions":[  
            {  
               "suggestion":"finger",
               "score":0.903614003311793
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "offset":13,
         "token":"harting",
         "type":"UnknownToken",
         "suggestions":[  
            {  
               "suggestion":"hurting",
               "score":0.903614003311793
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

This is my java code using Apache's HTTPClient library:
(note: "command.getAfter()" is the passed string I mentioned above. I debugged it and even hard coded a string to test it out. Same output obviously.)

```
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/");
            builder.setParameter("text", command.getAfter());
            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "XXXXXXXX");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

EDIT: It turns out the URI returned in the request object returns this:
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/?text=my+funger+is+harting+me

So the parameter is not empty? But when fed no text parameter in hurl.it, the api returns an error of no parameters. When the text parameter is a space " ", it returns an identical result to mine. Unsure what this means since the URI seems to be valid and not empty and my subscription key is working because i would get an error if it weren't...

EDIT: I'm starting to suspect the Apache library is ignoring the parameters I'm passing in HttpGet(uri). I'm unsure, but I'm going to try a different solution to send the request with a header and see what happens.

EDIT: I tried the following code below:

```
String url = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/?text=" + command.getAfter().replace(" ", "+");
                try {
                    URL request_url = new URL(url);
                    //URIBuilder uri = new URIBuilder("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/");
                    //uri.setParameter("text", command.getAfter());

                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) request_url.openConnection();
                    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    con.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", Keys.BING_SPELL_CHECK_API);
                    con.setConnectTimeout(100000);
                    con.setReadTimeout(100000);
                    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    String theString = IOUtils.toString(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
                    System.out.println(theString);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

It returned the same result as the Apache one... :/ What else should I try?

EDIT:
This is the output of the request as well:

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/?text=my+funger+is+hartingme - [Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <XXXXXXXXXXXX>]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK - en_US
{"_type": "SpellCheck", "flaggedTokens": []}
```

I don't get it.... Why is the json outputted empty when hurl.it returns the correct json for this same request? Is this a java issue or something?

EDIT:
I just tried UniRest's api. Exact same result... What am I doing wrong here?!
I'm so lost...

**Separate Issue:**
I do want to note the following: When I set the bing api's version to 7.0, I get the following error:

```
Received http status code 401 with message Access Denied and body {"message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription.","statusCode":401}
```

This is not the case with v5.0. I'm getting the correct key from my Azure portal. (The page called Keys and lists 2 keys you can use and regenerate)

Comment: What's the output of `request.getURI()`?

Comment: @JeremiahMegel I just checked.

    https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/?text=my+funger+is+harting+me

Could I be passing the parameter incorrectly?

Comment: Your code works for me. I'm using JDK 1.8 and `httpclient-4.5.3.jar` and `httpcore-4.4.7.jar` and `commons-logging-1.2.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Answer to getting v7.0 to work:

> This is not the case with v5.0. I'm getting the correct key from my Azure portal. **(The page called Keys and lists 2 keys you can use and regenerate)**

You get 2 keys *per* version. So if you are seeing 2 keys, they are likely both for v5.0. It should explicitly mention v7.0.
There should be different sections, also with different endpoints.
Use these in combination with each other to get the desired result.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZQOocgg.png Incorrect. This is the whole Keys page. The EndPoint in my dashboard says v5.0 only. No other endpoint or tab that says otherwise exists. Do note: my key and link returned a CORRECT JSON result on hurl.it. Therefore, the issue is not in the Keys at all because those are passing successfully on that website.